# Tombstone symbol

Tags: symbols

I would like to change the predefined tombstone symbol to the first one on the website  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Halmos.png (the square in a black frame).

[image]

How can I do it, please?

Comment: Isn't it the default?

Comment: You said "the predefined symbol", but we need to see how you build your  theorem-like structures, because when using `amsthm` the predefined symbols is precisely the one you want.

Comment: @egreg -- the default depends on the document class or theorem package used.  also, i don't believe that there is a *bold* open square.  all the "box" symbols in the comprehensive symbols list have thin walls, as in the second symbol shown.

Comment: I'm using the amsthm package as well, but the predefined symbol for the end of any proof looks almost like the second one on the picture above - square with thin walls. I would like to put in my work exactly the same as the first one-square with thick walls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `amsthm`, you need to redefine the `\qedsymbol` (in the preamble of your document if the change must apply to all the document). One option would be to use the `\Squarepipe` command from the `marvosym` package; here's a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\Squarepipe}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}test\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can define your own square; here's a comparison between the default symbol, the `\Squarepipe` command from `marvosym` and a customized `\BoldSquare` newly defined (you can change the values for `\fboxrule` and the arguments of `\rule` according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\newcommand\BoldSquare{%
  \setlength\fboxrule{1.1pt}\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\fbox{\phantom{\rule{5pt}{5pt}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}test\end{proof}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\Squarepipe}
\begin{proof}test\end{proof}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\BoldSquare}
\begin{proof}test\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Jane of course it is, did you see the last part of my answer? The `\BoldSquare` command doesn't require any package. Simply use `\newcommand\BoldSquare{\setlength\fboxrule{1.1pt}\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\fbox{\phantom{\rule{5pt}{5pt}}}} \renewcommand\qedsymbol{\BoldSquare}` in the preamble.

Comment: @Jane in that case, please edit your question and add a simple (but *complete*) document showing how you are using my definition and illustrating that it is not working.

Comment: @Jane the last one was obtained with the settings of my example... Would you like us to continue the discussion in a chat room? That will allow us to detect and correct your problem quickly...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3515/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-jane)

Comment: @Jane if you want to, please follow the link in the above comment (the one with "continue this discussion in chat") and we can quickly solve your problem.

Comment: @ Gonzola: It works now. I'm really sorry, it was my fault, I overlooked the second part of the command. I forgot to write \renewcommand\qedsymbol{\BoldSquare}. One more time sorry for complications and thanks for your help

Comment: @Jane: no problem. I am glad to hear that now everything works!